# How can I draw a line while only using vertices and indices?

Tags: rust, graphics, wgpu-rs

I use wgpu as my graphics backend for my project.

this is my current implementation:

```
pub fn draw_line(
    points: Vec<[f32; 2]>,
) -> (Vec<Vertex>, Vec<u16>) {
    let mut vertices: Vec<Vertex> = Vec::new();
    let mut indices: Vec<u16> = Vec::new();

    let w = WIDTH / 2.0;

    let x1 = points[0][0];
    let x2 = points[1][0];
    let y1 = points[0][1];
    let y2 = points[1][1];

    let color: [f32; 3] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0];

    vertices.push(Vertex { position: [x1,  y1 - w, 0.0],   color });
    vertices.push(Vertex { position: [x1,  y1 + w, 0.0],   color });
    vertices.push(Vertex { position: [x2,  y2 + w, 0.0],   color });
    vertices.push(Vertex { position: [x2,  y2 - w, 0.0],   color });

    indices.push(2);
    indices.push(1);
    indices.push(0);
    indices.push(2);
    indices.push(0);
    indices.push(3);

    return (vertices, indices);
}
```

But when trying to draw a line between 2 points the width of the line gets distorted relative to the height difference of those points.
And the X and Y values of point1 must be smaller than the ones on point2 otherwise they dont show up because wgpu needs either Clockwise or CounterClockwise front faces

[image: line_1]
[image: line_2]

Is there any better function that that returns the vertices and indices, for a line between 2 Points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but should work:

```
pub fn draw_line(
    points: Vec<[f32; 2]>,
) -> (Vec<Vertex>, Vec<u16>) {
    let mut vertices: Vec<Vertex> = Vec::new();
    let mut indices: Vec<u16> = Vec::new();

    let w = WIDTH / 2.0;

    let x1 = points[0][0];
    let x2 = points[1][0];
    let y1 = points[0][1];
    let y2 = points[1][1];

    let color: [f32; 3] = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0];

    let dx = x2 - x1;
    let dy = y2 - y1;
    let l = dx.hypot (dy);
    let u = dx * WIDTH * 0.5 / l;
    let v = dy * WIDTH * 0.5 / l;

    vertices.push(Vertex { position: [x1 + v,  y1 - u, 0.0],   color });
    vertices.push(Vertex { position: [x1 - v,  y1 + u, 0.0],   color });
    vertices.push(Vertex { position: [x2 - v,  y2 + u, 0.0],   color });
    vertices.push(Vertex { position: [x2 + v,  y2 - u, 0.0],   color });

    indices.push(2);
    indices.push(1);
    indices.push(0);
    indices.push(2);
    indices.push(0);
    indices.push(3);

    return (vertices, indices);
}
```